# IBM Bluemix ibm_db dashDB module 0.0.15 no longer compiles; module upgrade perhaps?

Tags: node.js, npm, ibm-cloud, dashdb

Has there been a recent "ibm_db" for dashDB module upgrade?
We have been using the Bluemix node.js and ibm_db module to access dashDB. The module has worked ok but now on 10.5.2016 the module no longer compiles on Bluemix. The version we have been using is defined in package.json as ibm_db ^0.0.15. Below is an example of the Bluemix building error log.

```
----->Building dependencies
   Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
   Rebuilding any native modules
   > ibm_db@0.0.15 install /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/ibm_db
   > node installer/driverInstall.js
   module.js:327
   throw err;
   ^
   Error: Cannot find module 'fstream'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
   at download_file_httpget (/tmp/staged/app/node_modules/ibm_db/installer/driverInstall.js:25:19)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/staged/app/node_modules/ibm_db/installer/driverInstall.js:340:1)
   at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
   npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
   npm ERR! argv "/tmp/staged/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/staged/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
   npm ERR! node v4.4.3
   npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! ibm_db@0.0.15 install: `node installer/driverInstall.js`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the ibm_db@0.0.15 install script 'node installer/driverInstall.js'.
   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ibm_db package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node installer/driverInstall.js
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs ibm_db
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls ibm_db
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/staged/app/npm-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update to `ibm_db 0.0.18` to use with Node.js `4.x`.

Per your logs you are using Node.js `4.4.3`, so your `package.json` file should be something like:

```
{
        "name": "NodejsStarterApp",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "private": true,
        "scripts": {
                "start": "node app.js"
        },
        "dependencies": {
                "express": "4.13.x",
                "cfenv": "1.0.x",
                "ibm_db": "0.0.18"
        },
        "repository": {},
        "engines": {
                "node": "4.x"
        }
}
```

Comment: Your answer solved the case. In Bluemix there is also node version 0.12.x, and this version compiles happily ibm_db 0.0.15.